# Get current element on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, click, this

I have two divs with same class `pan-detail-div` and have a span tag.
When user clicks on that span tag,I want to get that div. For example if user clicks span of left side div, It should return only that div
but currently I am getting both divs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pan-detail-div" style="float=left;">
<span class="show-more"></span>
</div>

<div class="pan-detail-div">
<span class="show-more"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".show-more").click(function () {
    var providerContainer = $(this).parents().find(".pan-detail-div");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> .closest( selector ): For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".show-more").click(function (e) {
    var providerContainer = $(this).closest(".pan-detail-div");
    console.log(providerContainer[0].outerHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="pan-detail-div" style="float=left;">
    <span class="show-more">span1</span>
</div>
<div class="pan-detail-div">
    <span class="show-more">span2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent()` should do the trick.

Note the difference between `parent` and `parents`, as the two functions do very different things. An element can only ha a *single* parent, and that's what `parent` retrieves. `parents` walks up the DOM tree, and returns all of the ancestors.

**In practice:**

```
$(".show-more").click(function () {
    var providerContainer = $(this).parent();
}
```

**Docs:**

- [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

  > Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
- [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

  > Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Comment: Then why is it retrieving both?

Comment: @HumaAli because you are using the plural form, `parents`, which is - in this case - incorrect.